# Minimum Deployment vs Target Deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

What is the main difference between the term minimum deployment and target deployment in Xcode?

I notice that I have to set up these two target versions, but I am not sure whether these two are different or same stuff just different words?

Answer (score 11):

The Target Deployment you are referring to is in the "Project" section. This specifies the default Minimum Deployment for targets created as part of this project. 
The Minimum Deployment is set per target and specifies the minimum OS version this particular target will support.

Comment: But why when I set deployment target to iOS 16, with minimum deployments iOS 15, I still can compile?

Comment: That is because minimum deployment is the actual iOS SDK you are compiling against. Target Deployment is only used when you don't specify minimum deployment in your target or create a brand new target in your project.

Comment: Confusing when you only have 1 target but I guess the project could have a deployment target of 16 which new targets will get but an existing target could be set to 15. Or, even more confusing, an existing target is set to 16 and you change your project target to 15 and wonder why the target still compiles.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Project level has actually any actual use anymore, because the targets seem to be set explicitly, but I still use it as shorthand in the project so I can remember what version dependencies the project might have.